# How can I add accumulative Margin on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add a text slider, where basically a very long text box extends out of the view, and when a button is pressed margin is added so more text can be read. I do not know how to make a button that adds margin without exponentially increasing it each time.

```
<div class='long'>
  <div class='container'>
          <button type="button" onclick="display()">Add left margin</button>
  <p id="myID">This is demo text.</p>
  <script>
     function display() {
        var e = document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft += 1  document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft; 
     }
  </script>
```

After a few clicks, this starts to increase the margin insane amounts. I believe it is because the 1 is not 1px, but some other unit which makes it add up insanely quick. SO I want to have a button that adds 1px of margin per click, so it smoothly adds margin instead of a big unuseable jump.

My hypothesis is that you need to get the margin value, store it, then add it to a string that has 'px' at the end then update the margin with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with your thoughts. Store the margin value in a variable outside the function, and increase it by one each time.

The `style.marginLeft` returns `1px` and not `1` which means you cannot increment to it.

```js
var margin = 1; 
function display() {
    document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = ++margin + "px";
}
```

```html
<div class='long'>
  <div class='container'>
          <button type="button" onclick="display()">Add left margin</button>
  <p id="myID">This is demo text.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parseInt and parseFloat functions will return numeric value for marginLeft (i.e. without the trailing 'px' that is causing your issue).

```
function display() {
    let el = document.getElementById("myID");
    el.style.marginLeft = `${parseInt(el.style.marginLeft)+1}px`;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that happen string concatenation when you use the `+` operator
You have to convert the value returned from `element.style.marginLeft` to a number. You can call the `Number()` function or use the `+` operator immediately attached how in my solution. Another problem could be that the value returned is like that `1px` for example and to increment it you have to parse it, I used `split` function

```
function display() {
           let currentMarginValue = +document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft.split('px')[0];
           console.log(currentMarginValue)
          var e = document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = currentMarginValue + 1 + "px" ;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need one counter that will increase in every click. please refer below code

```
  <script>
  let count = 0;
     function display() {
     document.getElementById("myID").style.marginLeft = ++count+"px";
     }
  </script>
```